# When doing a PCA analysis, how can we know which principal components were selected?

Tags: machine-learning, pca

I read the article from the link below.

https://towardsdatascience.com/principal-component-analysis-pca-with-scikit-learn-1e84a0c731b0

The author does a nice job describing the process of PCA decomposition. I feel like I understand everything except for one thing. How can we know which principal components were selected and thus preserver for eventual improved performance of our ML algos?  For instance, the author starts with this.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
cancer = load_breast_cancer()
df = pd.DataFrame(data=cancer.data, columns=cancer.feature_names)
df.head()
```

[image]

Ok, I know what the features are. Great. Then all the fun happens, and we end up with this at the end.

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(X_pca_95, columns=['PC1','PC2','PC3','PC4','PC5','PC6','PC7','PC8','PC9','PC10'])
df_new['label'] = cancer.target
df_new
```

Of the 30 features that we started with, how do we know what the final 10 columns consist of? It seems like there has to be some kind of last step to map the `df_new` to `df`?

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand, you need to know a little bit more about PCA. In fact, PCA returns all principal components that shape the whole space of vectors, i.e., eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the covariance matrix of features. Hence, you can select eigenvectors based on the size of their corresponding eigenvalues. Hence, you need to pick up the biggest eigenvalues and their corresponding eigenvectors.

Now if you look at the documentation of PCA method in scikit learn, you find some useful properties like the following:

> **components_ ndarray of shape (n_components, n_features)**: Principal axes in feature space, representing the directions of maximum variance in the data. **The components are sorted by explained_variance_.**

> **explained_variance_ratio_ ndarray of shape (n_components,)**
> Percentage of variance explained by each of the selected components.
> If n_components is not set then all components are stored and the sum of the ratios is equal to 1.0.

`explained_variance_ratio_` is a very useful property that you can use it to select principal components based on the desired threshold for the percentage of the covered variance. For example, take values in this array are `[0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1]`. If we take the first three components, the covered variance is `90%` of the whole variance of the original data.

Comment: I think I understand. Thanks for the explanation. So, the answer to my questions is, we can not get those original feature names at the end. Correct?

Comment: @ASH it's right. You will have the projection of the original feature vectors in the space of the selected eigenvectors at the end, not the original features.

Answer (score 0):

Almost surely the 10 resulting columns are all composed of pieces of all 30 original features.  The `PCA` object has an attribute `components_` that shows the coefficients defining the principal components in terms of the original features.